# Simulate stars and bars problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, simulation

Suppose that I have $n$ balls to be divided among $k$ buckets so that each bucket has a non-negative number of balls. This is a classic [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): the number of ways to do this division is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. (In my application, $k>>n$.)

I would like to run a simulation where, for each repetition, I can randomly select one of the $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ possible divisions. But I do not know how to make this random selection.

> Could you please help with an algorithm?

I have a feeling that I just need to find the right discrete distribution and simulate realizations of it, but I do not know how to arrive at this discrete distribution.

Comment: Why not just generate $n$ random integers in the range $[1,k]$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you mean $k$ random integers in the range $[1,n]$?

Comment: @Brian Scott I think the OP wants each distribution to be equally likely.  With your proposed algorithm it it very unlikely that all the balls end up in the same bucket, for example.

Comment: @yurnero: No: I mean generate a bucket number for each ball.

Comment: @saulspatz: Yes, now that you mention it, you’re probably right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. That is what I am looking for, although I might have phrased the problem incorrectly, as saulspatz comments. How should I phrase the problem better so that your algorithm is what I want? If you make this into an answer, I'll tick.

Comment: When $k \gg n$ I think an asymptotically optimal way to proceed is to just choose a bin independently at random for each ball.

Comment: (Cont.) By contrast, when $n \gg k$ it is more computationally efficient to choose the occupation number for each bin, and the occupation numbers are of course dependent, so to proceed one bucket at a time, you have to sort out this dependence. One way to do that is to choose an occupation number with a probability proportional to the number of ways to populate the bins you haven't populated yet, i.e. when there are $m$ balls remaining and $j$ buckets remaining you populate the current bucket with $i$ balls with probability proportional to ${(m-i)+(j-1)-1 \choose (j-1)-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simulate choosing a bucket at random for each ball, you can simply generate $n$ random integers in the range $[1,k]$. If you want to generate each possible distribution of balls with equal probability, you could generate $n$ different random integers in the range $[1,n+k-1]$ and use them in conjunction with the stars-and-bars model to generate the associated distribution.

Comment: MUCH better than my idea.